# replacing ceiling fan with standard light

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

I originally had a ceiling light with a smoke detector in the ceiling. After removing it, I discovered two black, two white, two red and one ground wire in a single box.

When I turn on the switch, only one set of black and white is live (tested with a voltage pen). The two red are always live.

I tried to wire the new light to the set of black and white that will go live when the switch is on but the new light will not turn on when the light bulb is attached. Can someone help me understand this setup? Thanks.

Comment: A light _with_ a smoke detector? As in an integrated unit?

Comment: Yes, it was fan+light+smoke detector of sorts.

Comment: The live reds are a mystery. With modern smoke detectors they're simply a low-voltage interconnect, but I'm not sure why there would be two here. Please update your post with information about how the original fixture was connected.

Comment: I honestly do not remember how the original fixture was connected. I should've taken a picture when I removed it back then.

Comment: I suggest getting yourself an inexpensive multi-meter and checking actual voltages. Whether the reds are line-level or low-voltage would be good to know.

Comment: Yep, I have that, I can provide an update tonight

Comment: By "live" do you mean there's voltage **between** black and white, or that both of those go hot relative to the ground wire?   I would also look at the wire(s) coming from the switch itself to verify their colors.

Comment: I'm more confused after testing. The 2 red wire, 1 is hot (120v), the other is neutral. The first set of black and white, black is hot (120v), white is hot when tested with a pen, but no voltage when tested with multimeter. The second set of black and white, both have no voltage (neutral?).